# Square shape initial condition in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, wave-equation, initial-value-problems, finite-differences

I am analyzing $1$D convection equation in MATLAB using Finite Difference method
I would like to start the concentration $C(x,t)$ with a square pulse, and see how this square moves in space and time.
Here is my Initial condition in the code

`% Initial Condition for i = 1:m if (x(i) >= 0) && (x(i) <=L) C(i,1) = 1; elseif (x(i) > 0.5) && (x(i) <= L) C(i,1) = x(i); end end`

Comment: Do you know the existence of heaviside (step) function in Matlab ? It allows to write at once the characteristic function of an interval in the following way for example for interval [-1,2]: t=-3:0.01:3;plot(t,heaviside(t+1).*heaviside(2-t));

Comment: Hi Jean, thanks. It is supposed to see ripples at the square edges, how can I do this?
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4079464/square-pulse-test-of-upwind-finite-differences

Comment: Ripples may come from convolution with cardinal sine, itself the Fourier transform of a rectangular function